# Best practice for List of values in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm looking for best practices on creating a LOV model in rails.
Imagine something simple like 2 models `users` and `companies`. Both have a field name `type` so they both could have a related table named `user_types` and `company_types`.

How can this be done using only one table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way is to define UserType and CompanyType models and tables:

```
class UserType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

class CompanyType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :type, class_name: 'UserType'
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :type, class_name: 'CompanyType'
end
```

So, you have 4 tables: **user_types**, **company_types**, users, companies.

In next level, you can implement STI (Single Table Inheritance):

```
class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class UserType < Type
  has_many :users
end

class CompanyType < Type
  has_many :users
end
```

*You need to add "type" column to Type model with string type.*

In this example you have only **3** tables: **types**, users, companies.

You can learn more about STI with following links: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance/ClassMethods.html

Also you can use one of key/value stores for types like redis, riak, etc. But in my opinion it is overkill for your issue.